# CLLocationManager didEnterRegion not fired at initial location

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am creating an app that monitors regions in the background and I can receive `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` just fine in and outside of the application. My one problem is that during testing I have one region right where I work and when I start the application (I clear the regions at startup and exit) I'd expect `didEnterRegion` to fire for this region, but it's not. Apparently the system believes I am inside the region however, since I will receive `didExitRegion` when I move outside of it. If I then move back into the region it will trigger like it should.

I have tried using `requestStateForRegion` during initializing like this:

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:region];
```

and then implementing the callback as:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (state == CLRegionStateInside) {
        [self locationManager:manager didEnterRegion:region];
    }
}
```

But this callback never triggers so I have no idea how I should proceed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990115/beacon-ios-cllocationmanager-get-current-region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple: As apple states in the documentation only boundary events will trigger the delegate method call.

But why do you need this? If you know the region, you can just test at the moment when you start the app whether you are inside or not, right?

If it's a circular region you can just go ahead and do this

```
CLLocation *myLocation = CURRENT_LOCATION; 
CLCircularRegion* region = YOUR_REGION;
CLLocation *regionCenter = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:region.center.latitude longitude:region.center.longitude];

if([region distanceFromLocation:regionCenter]<region.radius)
{
   // YOU ARE IN THE REGION!!
}
```

Or just use:

```
CLLocation *myLocation = CURRENT_LOCATION; 
CLCircularRegion* region = YOUR_REGION;
if([region containsCoordinate:myLocation.coordinate])
{
   //YOU ARE IN THE REGION!!
}
```

Comment: I suppose I'll have to do it manually then. I'm only worried that my own calculations wouldn't match the ones made by the system. For example some circular regions have a radius of 25 meters but the system triggers them at what seems to be 100 meters (and AFAIK it doesn't get much better than that). A manual calculation wouldn't take this into account and there would be a deadzone in the outer circle (from 25m to 100m) if I'm not mistaken? In any case the second piece of code looks promising and I'll try it out!

Comment: The second piece of code actually does exactly the same. The reason why the boundary condition may also trigger at 100m is that the horizontal accuracy of you location (myLocation.horizontalAccuracy) is >=75m and therefore calculates: ([region distanceFromLocation:regionCenter]<region.radius+myLocation.horizontalAccuracy/2 or something like this

Comment: Gonna need some testing but that solution is at least good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try`[locationMgrObj requestStateForRegion:regionObj]` to get the current state in `didDetermineState`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be calling 
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:region] in

`func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion)`