# Beacon / IOS CLLocationManager get current region

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I'm doing a program who is looking for beacon, I implemented CLLocationManager and my apps works except one point.
I'm calling startMonitoringForRegion() in order to get the didEnterRegion/didExitRegion callback. Inside these function I'm doing startRangingBeaconsInRegion()/stopRangingBeaconsInRegion() in order to get precise information when the user is in the beacon area.
My issue is quite simple, if the app is started when the user is already in the beacon range, didEnterRegion is not called.

I'm looking for a function like isInRegion() so that when my app start I could do startMonitoringForRegion() then isInRegion() and startRangingBeaconsInRegion() if the user is already in the region.

My current workaround is to call startRangingBeaconsInRegion() when the app start, then in the didRangeBeacons callback, I'm doing stopRangingBeaconsInRegion() if no beacon is found.
I don't think that it's a very clean way and would like to replace by something better if possible

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:` callback, which tells you if you are either `Inside`, `Outside` or `Unknown`.

You can force yourself to get a callback by calling

```
locationManager.requestStateForRegion(region)
```

when your app starts up.

See more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion: